# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "labelframe"

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I'm getting the following error when running a `python/tkinter` GUI application I wrote.

I thought it could be a Tcl/Tk version issue, but the `LabelFrame()` command was added in Tcl/Tk 8.4, (which is the version I am using).

The other computer that I am    attempting to execute the program on    is able to run another `python/tkinter` application I wrote--the difference between the applications is that one utilizes the `LabelFrame()` widget and the other does not.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nharris/python/isub_parser/isub.py", line 672, in <module>
    timeFrame = LabelFrame(optFrame, text="Time Scale Options")
  File "/usr/apps/Python/python2.6.1-rhel3-i686/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3525, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'labelframe', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/apps/Python/python2.6.1-rhel3-i686/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1932, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "labelframe"
```

Comment: what is the output of `import Tkinter;print Tkinter.TkVersion`

Comment: So using that method of version checking, it says 8.3. I was going off of: "To check, start Tcl/Tk (usually via running "tclsh" or "wish" from a command line), and typing "info patchlevel"." Which would output 8.4.15...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python may be using its own special version of TCL/TK, depending on how it was built and installed.  This is usually the case on on windows, sometimes the case on linux, and seldom the case on MacOS X.  You must rely on the version reported inside python to know what version it is using.

If python is not using the installed version (as is the case you are experiencing), you can try updating python.  If, on your distribution of linux, you cannot overcome the way python was built using available packages, you will have to build python from source to use a newer version of TCL/TK or to use the installed version.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get two different versions of Tcl/Tk reported using these two methods:

```
Method 1:
>tclsh
%info patchlevel
8.4.15

Method 2:
>python
>>>import Tkinter;print Tkinter.TkVersion
8.3

Key: 
> default command line
>>> python command line
% tcl command line
```

An update of Tcl/Tk should fix it.